# Changing the standard telegram authorization button to your own

Tags: javascript, html, telegram, custom-button

There is a standard telegram authorization script that contains an iframe, how to change the authorization button to your own?

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="samplebot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onTelegramAuth(user) {
    alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
  }
</script>
```

I looked for a work on github, but there are two codes with TypeScript, you need to use only JS and HTML, while all authorization interacts with PHP. I have already implemented authorization, but I can’t figure out how to change the parameter to my own.